# Populate ListView using List

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I am trying to display data from my sqlite database. In my **DatabaseHandler.java** I have this method:

```
public List<Item> getAllItemsinList() {
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            item.set_name(cursor.getString(1));
            item.set_description(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            itemList.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return item list
    return itemList;
}
```

It returns a List with the type `Item`.

In my **MainActivity.java** I have this method:

```
private void populateListViewUsingList(){
    List<Item> items;
    items = db.getAllItemsinList();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItems);
    ArrayAdapter<Item> itemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
}
```

The listview is populated, however, objects are being displayed instead of the data the database contains. Example of text being displayed is **migueld.rivera.catalogapp.Item@42a97320**. What is the correct way of parsing data? Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist?rq=1) question

Comment: You'll probably want to override the toString() method of Item to have it display correctly

Comment: My `Item` class does not a toString method currently. You are saying I should make one?

Comment: Yep, it's currently using the default implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Example of text being displayed is
>   migueld.rivera.catalogapp.Item@42a97320. What is the correct way of
>   parsing data?

ArrayAdapter take List of objects and call toString method on item return from `List.get` method. see here [getView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29) implementation from :

```
 T item = getItem(position);
 if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
   text.setText((CharSequence)item);

  } else {
    text.setText(item.toString());
 }
```

So,

**Option 1:** override toString method in `Item` class which return readable string representation of Item object

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(name + "---" + description);
}
```

**Option 2:** Create a custom Adapter by extending ArrayAdapter :

[Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: will look into these. so far option 2 is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @MiguelRivera: yes because after override getView method you can call all getter methods from Item class to get values and show in different TextView's

Comment: Hi @ρяσѕρєя K, the example displays a data from an array. Is it advisable to convert my `List<Item>` to an array or modify the Adapter class to accept a `List<e>`?

Comment: @MiguelRivera: No need to convert List to Array, just pass List object to Custom Adapter class and use List object instead of array in custom adapter class

Comment: worked like a charm. I've been into cross platform development and I got rusty in native coding. The tutorial was a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are direclty displaying the object. Try in this manner in your getview method of the adapter

```
Items item = getItem(position);

textView.setText(item.get_name()+....+item.get_description);
```

Use appropriate method name what you have declared in your class

Example for custom listview adapter in shown here
[ListView with custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755095/listview-with-custom-adapter)

Comment: She doesn't have an adapter yet. This might need to be expanded to include the fact you'd need to create a custom adapter